# Tests running silently without window appearing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, remote-desktop, selenium-grid

Apologies, I'm still fairly new to selenium so please bear with me as I explain this.

Currently my selenium tests are running on a remote machine but no window opens when I'm remotely logged into that machine!

My setup is:
Remote machine has 2 admin users with Selenium Grid2 and a node as a windows service.
The machine is running windows server 2012 with the services having Interactive services  enabled.

I am using Selenium 2.42.1 with IEDriver version 2.42.0

Tests are being built and run remotely on our build server.

I think that's everything, if there's any more information then please let me know as I'd really like to know why I cannot view my tests running.

Just for clarification, the tests are running and they successfully pass or fail where necessary, but I just can't see it if I'm remote logged into the machine.

**UPDATE**

There has been some interesting progress on this issue but still no resolution.
I decided to try and run a node from command line and funny enough the tests run with no problems and the browser window is displayed.

So if anyone has any idea why a browser window would appear when running a node from command line but not when running a node as a service would be great.

I'm using java service wrapper to create my service and im using the same nodeconfig.json when running the node.

Comment: how many nodes do you have up? maybe it's possible that you log into another machine, but the test actually fires against the other?

Comment: I have 1 node connected to the hub at the moment, to keep testing simple. It should be running on the machine im logging into, it's a bit odd as I logged into the machine using remote desktop and got the ip from ipconfig while connected and used that ip address when doing my tests, also I only have selenium hub running on a single machine.

Comment: Did you create the grid under you profile

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you are running the node as a windows service. There is an option in service to say whether the job should run in background or interact with desktop. Check that and you should see the windows.

[image: Services interaction]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem =( I already have that option checked when I installed the service.